# ¿Por qué :last-of-type no funciona, pero nth-of-type(n) sí lo hace?

Tags: css, formularios

Hice un formulario ficticio y estaba aplicándole estilos, hasta que uno de los estilos que puse no funcionó. Usando `class=".container__form-entry"` quiero que el elemento que escoja **ocupe las dos columnas del grid;** usando `nth-of-type(numero)` me funciona, pero usando `last-of-type`(o sea el último) no me está funcionando. Anteriormente me ha funcionado perfectamente pero **este caso en particular** no lo hace.(Buscar en el fragmento de css /**Raiz del problema*/ para ver la duda que tengo)

```css
:root{
    font-size: 62.5%;
    --lightbrown: #720;
    --brown: #600;
    --white: #fff;
}

body{
    font-family: "Splice Sans", sans-serif;
}

h3{
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    color: #113;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Utitities */

.centered-text{
    text-align: center;
}

.small-text.small-text{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

/* Main container */

.container__form{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 3rem repeat(auto-fill, minmax(5rem, 1fr));
    column-gap: 1rem;
    row-gap: 1rem;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 4rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 2px #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container__form h3{
    display: block;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.container__form-entry{
    text-align: center;
    background: var(--lightbrown);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: var(--white);
}

.container__form-entry textarea{
    resize: none;
}

.container__form-label{
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container__form-submit{
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}


/*Raiz del problema*/
.container__form-entry:last-of-type{
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
/*Raiz del problema*/

.reminder{
    color: #888;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    margin: auto;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    text-align: center;
}

.button{
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border:none;
    padding: 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: var(--lightbrown);
    color: var(--white);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 1.6rem 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="container__form">

                    <h3>Formulario de Contacto</h3>

                    <p class="reminder small-text">OJO: Esta página es solo un experimento; no existe una ruta para enviar los datos de este formulario, ni siquiera
                        una base de datos para guardar dichos datos. Al presionar el botón "Enviar" simplemente recargarás la página
                    </p>

                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="name" class="container__form-label">Nombres</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ej. Jesús David" required>
                    </div>
                    

                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="forename" class="container__form-label">Apellidos</label>
                        <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" placeholder="Ej. Tovar Pérez" required>
                    </div>


                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="email" class="container__form-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="ejemplo@ejemplo.com" required>
                    </div>


                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="phone-number" class="container__form-label">Número Telefónico</label>
                        <select name="phone-number-prefix" id="" required >
                            <option disabled selected>Seleccione un prefijo</option>
                            <option value="1">Estados Unidos(+1)</option>
                            <option value="34">España(+34)</option>
                            <option value="51">Perú(+51)</option>
                            <option value="53">Cuba(+53)</option>
                            <option value="54">Argentina(+54)</option>
                            <option value="55">Brasil(+55)</option>
                            <option value="57">Colombia(+57)</option>
                            <option value="58">Venezuela(+58)</option>
                            <option value="593">Ecuador(+593)</option>
                            <option value="850">Corea del Norte(+850)</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="tel" name="phone-number" id="phone-number" placeholder="Ej. +5812345678901" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="reason" class="container__form-label">¿Para qué nos contactas?</label>
                        <textarea name="" id="reason" cols="50" rows="8" placeholder="Indica tus razones" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container__form-submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="button">
                    </div>                  
                </form>
```

**OJO** el `textarea` sí es ancho simplemente porque le coloqué un `cols="50"`.

Reemplazando `last-of-type` por `nth-of-type(último)` en la *línea 71* **sí me funciona**(Buscar en el fragmento de css /**Raiz del problema*/ para ver la duda que tengo):

```css
:root{
    font-size: 62.5%;
    --lightbrown: #720;
    --brown: #600;
    --white: #fff;
}

body{
    font-family: "Splice Sans", sans-serif;
}

h3{
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    color: #113;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Utitities */

.centered-text{
    text-align: center;
}

.small-text.small-text{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

/* Main container */

.container__form{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 3rem repeat(auto-fill, minmax(5rem, 1fr));
    column-gap: 1rem;
    row-gap: 1rem;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 4rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 2px #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container__form h3{
    display: block;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.container__form-entry{
    text-align: center;
    background: var(--lightbrown);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: var(--white);
}

.container__form-entry textarea{
    resize: none;
}

.container__form-label{
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container__form-submit{
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.container__form-entry:nth-of-type(5){
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.reminder{
    color: #888;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    margin: auto;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    text-align: center;
}

.button{
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border:none;
    padding: 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: var(--lightbrown);
    color: var(--white);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 1.6rem 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="container__form">

                    <h3>Formulario de Contacto</h3>

                    <p class="reminder small-text">OJO: Esta página es solo un experimento; no existe una ruta para enviar los datos de este formulario, ni siquiera
                        una base de datos para guardar dichos datos. Al presionar el botón "Enviar" simplemente recargarás la página
                    </p>

                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="name" class="container__form-label">Nombres</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ej. Jesús David" required>
                    </div>
                    

                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="forename" class="container__form-label">Apellidos</label>
                        <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" placeholder="Ej. Tovar Pérez" required>
                    </div>


                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="email" class="container__form-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="ejemplo@ejemplo.com" required>
                    </div>


                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="phone-number" class="container__form-label">Número Telefónico</label>
                        <select name="phone-number-prefix" id="" required >
                            <option disabled selected>Seleccione un prefijo</option>
                            <option value="1">Estados Unidos(+1)</option>
                            <option value="34">España(+34)</option>
                            <option value="51">Perú(+51)</option>
                            <option value="53">Cuba(+53)</option>
                            <option value="54">Argentina(+54)</option>
                            <option value="55">Brasil(+55)</option>
                            <option value="57">Colombia(+57)</option>
                            <option value="58">Venezuela(+58)</option>
                            <option value="593">Ecuador(+593)</option>
                            <option value="850">Corea del Norte(+850)</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="tel" name="phone-number" id="phone-number" placeholder="Ej. +5812345678901" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container__form-entry">
                        <label for="reason" class="container__form-label">¿Para qué nos contactas?</label>
                        <textarea name="" id="reason" cols="50" rows="8" placeholder="Indica tus razones" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container__form-submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="button">
                    </div>                  
                </form>
```

Lo que quiero saber es a qué se debe este comportamiento, ya que me hace creer que `last-of-type` puede llegar a ser impredecible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `:last-of-type` y `:nth-of-type` no funcionan como a muchos nos gustaría. Querríamos que lo hiciera como si fuera una especie de `:last-of-class` y `:nth-of-class`, pero no es así.

Por ejemplo, lo que en verdad esta mirando cuando pones `.container__form-entry:last-of-type` es, en donde se encuentre un bloque con esa clase, si su último hermano del mismo tipo (`div`, `span`, ...) tiene esa clase, en ese caso aplica los estilos.

**Ejemplos**

Supongamos que tenemos este css, en el que, si `nth-of-type`nos funciona, pondrá el texto en rojo, y, si el `last-of-type` funciona, pondrá un color de fondo

```
.similar:nth-of-type(3) {
  color:red;
}

.similar:last-of-type {
  background-color:darkviolet;
}
```

**Ejemplo 1:** En el primer caso tenemos 3 bloques seguidos con la clase `similar`, y el último lleva la clase `diferente`:

```
<div class="similar">Similar</div>
<div class="similar">Similar</div>
<div class="similar">Similar</div>
<div class="diferente">Diferente</div>
```

En este caso el resultado sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como el último elemento no lleva la clase `similar` no aplica los estilos.

**Ejemplo 2:** Si intercambiamos la posición del último y penúltimo bloque:

```
<div class="similar">Similar</div>
<div class="similar">Similar</div>
<div class="diferente">Diferente</div>
<div class="similar">Similar</div>
```

En este segundo caso en la posición 3 no hay un bloque con la clase `similar`por lo cual no se aplican los estilos del `nth-of-type`. Pero, como el último elemento si tiene la clase, tiene color de fondo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ejemplo 3:** Como último ejemplo, añado al final un `span` con la clase similar:

```
<div class="similar">Similar</div>
<div class="similar">Similar</div>
<div class="diferente">Diferente</div>
<div class="similar">Similar</div>
<span class="similar">Similar</span>
```

El resultado es que pone color de fondo al último elemento `div` que lleva la clase `similar`, y también al útlimo `span` que lleva esa clase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva de ayuda